# Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' in Xcode 11

Tags: xcode11

Cannot initiate Main.storybard as the first screen.

Question:

Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

Workdone:
I tried to set the Main.storyboard as the initial view controller.

In the Info.plist, I also set the Launch screen interface file base name as Main

Result:
Nothing change. Problem still there.

Image:
[Storyboard attribute setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIFHU.png)
[Info.plist setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcaBP.png)

Answer (score -1):

have you tried creating a new view controller and setting it as the initial view controller? I think it "jumpstarts" the project.  Worked for me